# Different ways, for different platforms, to change GLFW 3 Window Icon in LWJGL 3.1

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

I'm creating a Game Engine that works with LWJGL 3.

I'm creating a class named 'FrameManager' wish handle Window inputs (Like Size, Position, etc) but I've looked for in many web sites, documentation etc, and I didn't find how to create a simple method wish set the Window icon.
First, I found a GLFW 3 method: `glfwSetWindowIcon(frameId, images);`

But it don't seems to work on macOS Sierra 1.12 (I cannot test on Window for the moment). 
Here is how i use this method:

```
                log.debug(" -> Setting Icon...");
                final PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(new FileInputStream(iconPath));
                final int iconWidth = decoder.getWidth();
                final int iconHeight = decoder.getHeight();
                final ByteBuffer buffer = createByteBuffer(iconWidth * iconHeight * 4);
                decoder.decode(buffer, iconWidth * 4, PNGDecoder.Format.RGBA);
                buffer.flip();
                final GLFWImage image = malloc();
                image.set(iconWidth, iconHeight, buffer);
                final GLFWImage.Buffer images = malloc(1);
                images.put(0, image);

                glfwSetWindowIcon(frameId, images);

                images.free();
                image.free();
```

I tried it before/after Window Creation/Show but nothing happen in macOS Sierra 10.12 (No Error, but no Icon).

So, i considered that it works on Window but not on Mac.

I looked for an Apple solution, than I found 2 ways, but it doesn't work :(

First, adding this in the VM launch args: `-Xdock:icon=/path/myIcon.png`

But nothing happen :(
And I also tried that:

```
Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(Image img);
```

It doesn't create an icon and interrupt the Thread (Thread is blocked at this moment).

I known that Application Bundle exists, but is-there really no other solution ?

Thanks for your help!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#gadd7ccd39fe7a7d1f0904666ae5932dc5) the GLFW icon API does not work, see the "Remarks" in the API documentation.

It mentions that you should use the bundles icon to set the dock bar icon.